# changing directories in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I am currently using Apache on Linux. I've been working on an HTML project, but now need to run it on a server.

So for example, even if the root directory is "/var/www/" and localhost/index.html points to "/var/www/index.html" I can make localhost/project/index.html point to "/project/index.html"

Can I also do this in .htaccess files?

Answer (score 2):

You want [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias), but that won't work in .htaccess files. You'd have to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for those.